# WCF IsFault and FaultException

Tags: .net, wcf

OK, I am getting myself a little confused here. I have a WCF service (service A) that calls another WCF service (service B). When I throw an exception on Service B e.g. `throw new Exception("test")` then service A does not get an exception, instead the IsFault is set to true on the response message e.g.

```
responseMessage = forwardingChannel.Process(message)
if (responseMessage.IsFault) {
    // Yes, there is a fault
}
```

I expected that I could put a try-catch around the Process method and receive the exception. Could someone explain to me what is going on here please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Service A were a Java service, would you expect to get a .NET exception back from calling Service B?

By default, an unhandled exception in a WCF Service will be returned as fault. If the service is using SOAP, that will be returned as a SOAP Fault. In a normal WCF client, that will get translated into a FaultException.

Comment: OK thanks for the reply, but how do you get the SOAP Fault translated into a FaultException? Why doesn't that automatically happen on my WCF service but would do on a client?

Thanks again

Comment: If you use Add Service Reference in a client, then a SOAP Fault returned by the service _will_ be translated into a FaultException.

Comment: Yes, but in the case of an intermediary service you won't have a reference in the same way, so how do you then translate it? Thanks

Comment: In exactly the same way! Look at the fault to try to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I am doing this

MessageFault messageFault = MessageFault.CreateFault(response, int.MaxValue);
throw new FaultException(messageFault);

I assume this is the right way to do it then